# Get all models in a backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js

I know there is a collection.models method that returns an array of the models. 
Is this the best practice to use or is there a way to return all models from a collection. The term raw is confusing and frightening to me.

> Raw access to the JavaScript array of models inside of the collection.
>   Usually you'll want to use get, at, or the Underscore methods to
>   access model objects, but occasionally a direct reference to the array
>   is desired.

Comment: If you simply want all Model objects from your Collection, the `.models` property on your instance is the way to go. Most of the time you're extracting some subset of models based on some criteria (filter, index, etc).

Comment: But what if you want access to all the models and their attributes.

Comment: ...you just access them. They're instances of Backbone.Model.

Comment: So if I set a variable after the initialize is run on a model example: this.value = 20; I can't access it if I do collection.models. When I look at what comes back from collection.models its not showing the value variable I set on each one.

Comment: Also if I do a .get(attribute) on any of the models I get back from collection.models. it gives me an error Uncaught TypeError: selected.get is not a function

Comment: `this.value = 20` on a model will set a property on the model object itself, and not it's attributes. You should be using `this.set('value',20)`

Answer (score 5):

If you have a collection called studentsData. Do this

```
var data = studentsData.toJSON()
```

The variable **data** is going to have an array of objects (array of model attributes).